# What does the number in Trello title mean?

Tags: trello

When looking at Trello, I see number in a page title / tabl title.

It looks like

> (3) ProjectName | Trello

I have no idea what does the number refer to. There are no new messages, no new cards, no new lists. And it makes me a little nervous.

Comment: As you noticed below, it is an indicator that you have unread notifications. =D

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. I find it funny that while you didn't know what it was, it still picked on your brain, like something was pending. Like if there's something you had to know about. Which is the very exact purpose of that number. I guess it makes the right effect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, it refers to the notifications on top right.

I never actually clicked that icon and I use Trello for months.

All right.